# Python Complex Number Operations

Tags: python, complex-numbers, python-cmath

I have an equation

```
(0.125-(1j*(mu1)*0.125))/(0.125 - cmath.sqrt((0.125**2)-(0.125**2)-((mu1**2)*(0.125**2))))
```

This is suppose to be 1 for any value of mu1 but it seems I am getting 1 only if mu1 is real... what am I missing?

```
For mu1 = 1, the above expression calculates 1 (see 3rd line)
(0.125-(1j*(mu1)*0.125))/(0.125 - cmath.sqrt((0.125**2)-(0.125**2)-((mu1**2)*(0.125**2))))
(1+0j)
```

```
For mu1 = 2, the above expression calculates 1 (see 3rd line)
(0.125-(1j*(mu1)*0.125))/(0.125 - cmath.sqrt((0.125**2)-(0.125**2)-((mu1**2)*(0.125**2))))
(1-0j)  ANSWER I AM LOOKING FOR
```

```
For mu1 = 2+2j, the above expression calculates
(0.125-(1j*(mu1)*0.125))/(0.125 - cmath.sqrt((0.125**2)-(0.125**2)-((mu1**2)*(0.125**2))))
(-1.4-0.8j) I WAS EXPECTING 1 because NUMERATOR and DENOMINATOR are same
```

For the last one, the bottom half evaluates to

```
1                     1
-- - sqrt(j^2 (2+2j)^2 ---^2 )
8                     8

1              1
-- - j (2+2j) ---
8              8

1 -2j -2j^2
-----------
8

3 - 2j
------
8
```

Comment: The `(0.125**2)-(0.125**2)` part of your equation cancels out to zero - I suspect you've miscopied some part of it.

Comment: No its ok.. They are suppose to cancel out and the sqrt should give j*mu1*0.125

Comment: In the original eq, both 0.125 is replaced by variables a and b.. I gave a easier expression to make my point

Comment: After cancelling out everything, the result will only be 1 when `1j*mu1*0.125 == cmath.sqrt(-(mu1**2 * 0.125**2))`

Comment: Yes... that's what my question... I am getting 1 only if mu1 is real and not if mu1 is complex.... I thought they are essentially same expression...cmath.sqrt(-1) == 1j

Comment: They are not essentially the same; the left hand side can be any complex number, but the right hand side can only be the principal square root of a complex number, so it's just not logically possible for that equation to be an identity.

Comment: Can you please explain why its not because the same mu1 var exists in both LHS and RHS... At the most, there is atleast one soln where  they are same

Comment: Equations *equate* two things; you have an *expression*.

Answer (score 0):

After cancelling out the common terms, the result will only be `1` when

```
1j*mu1*0.125 == cmath.sqrt(-(mu1**2 * 0.125**2))
```

I haven't analyzed it carefully, but it seems to be true only the real part of `mu1` is positive or zero and the imaginary part is negative or zero. I.e. it's true in the lower-right quadrant of the complex plane.

So I think you may have been misinformed about the equation, or you copied it wrong.

Comment: LHS == RHS regardless of mu1 being real or complex...

Comment: @user3873617 Evidently not.

Comment: @kaya3 why is that???

Comment: Why is it evident? Because you can see for yourself that the left hand side is not equal to the right hand side in some cases.

Comment: @user3873617 It seems like [math.se] might be a better place for you to ask about this formula.

Comment: I dont see they are being different... The poster who posted the prev answer is correcting it now... If you have some calc, please post it

Comment: @kaya3 I think u are assuming that they are equation.. they are not each line is output from python shell.... I removed the ">>>" characters to make them readable...

Comment: @user3873617 They are not equal. You cannot square something, then take a square root, and always expect to get back the same number you started with; squaring is not an invertible operation. As I wrote above, the left hand side can be any complex number whereas the right hand side can only be a principal square root.

Comment: So you saying that for a complex number c, this is not true j c = sqrt(-c^2)

Comment: @Barmar I posted my question on math.stackexchange too. Thanks

Comment: @user3873617 Every number has two square roots. E.g. the square roots of 4 are 2 and -2. But `math.sqrt()` only returns one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in using appropriate branch cuts of sqrt function.

Answer (score -1):

In your case of `2+2j` the top half of the fraction resolves to:

```
 1       j(2 + 2j)
---  -  -----------
 8           8

 1    -   (2j + (2j)^2)
---------------------
          8

 1    -   (2j + 2*-1)
---------------------
          8

 1    -   2j + 2
---------------------
          8

     3    -   2j 
---------------------
          8
```

Which only happens with the complex input due to `j^2 = -1`

The bottom half is:

```
(-0.125+0.25j)

# or
 
 -1 + 2j
--------
   8

# Because:

 1        sqrt(0 -      (2+2j)^2      )
---   -       -------------------
 8                 8^2


 1         sqrt(   -       8j
---  -                  -------     )
 8                         8^2

 1       2      2j
---  - (--- - -----)
 8       8      8

 1       2      2j
---  -  --- +  -----
 8       8      8

 -1 + 2j
--------
   8
```

It's worth noting this difference:

```
>>> cmath.sqrt(8j/64)
(0.25+0.25j)
>>> cmath.sqrt(-8j/64)
(0.25-0.25j)
```

Comment: The bottom also evaluates to (3-2j)/8

Comment: I added the bottom half calc that I see... How are you getting (2-2j)/8

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct, I'll update my answer

Comment: I agree with other posters, this probably would be easier resolved on Mathematics StackExchange if you're still not satisfied. Fun times revisiting complex number theory! Also - they probably have proper formatting tools - trying to write formulae on here is not easy.

Comment: Your 3rd line is incorrect... I have added the bottom calc in my orig...